# Failing to call a function using GetProcAddress in my own dll

Tags: c++, winapi

I have two projects, one is AddExec and the other is DllAdd.
AddExec loads DllAdd and calls the Add function after retrieving the address through GetProcAddress..

Here's my main.cpp for AddExec

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
typedef int(__cdecl*AddPtrType) (int x, int y);
int main()
{
    HMODULE DllAddModule = LoadLibraryA("DllAdd.dll");
    if (DllAddModule == NULL)
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Failed to get address : " << error;
        return -1;
    }
        
    AddPtrType AddLocal = (AddPtrType)GetProcAddress(DllAddModule, "Add");
    if (AddLocal == NULL)
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Failed to get address : " << error;
        return -1;
    }
    int x = AddLocal(10, 15);
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

And here's my main.cpp for DllAdd.dll

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

The function inside DllAdd is called Add. But when I attempt to retrieve its address I get error code 127

```
ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND
127 (0x7F)
The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I don't know why it can't find the address.. I Am exporting it and using the exact function names

Comment: What happens if you rename main.cpp to main.c for your DllAdd.dll?

Comment: That worked! Can you explain

Comment: *I don't know why it can't find the address.* -- Use a tool such as Dependency Walker, dumpbin, or similar to actually get the name that has been exported by the DLL.  The `GetProcAddress` function requires the *exact* name to be used -- even the casing of the name matters.  If you had done that, you would have seen that the name of the exported function is not `Add`, but something else.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've never used dependency walker.. I'll try it! I don't know what you mean by casting of the name matters though

Comment: @Kayla -- Casing means `Func` is not the same as `func`.  Both of those are different functions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ah okay! So even casing of the name matters when looking for procedures..sorry I read that as "casting" not casing..that was my mistake

Comment: Why are you linking with GetProcAddress? Have you considered using a def file?

Comment: @Kayla -- Yes, the `GetProcAddress` is very simple in that the name you give it must match exactly with the name that's exported.   This means everything, casing, special characters, etc.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't really know how to do that lol..

Comment: @Kayla -- The .def file lets you basically give the exported function a "nice" name instead of something ugly.

Comment: @Kayla [Exporting from a DLL Using DEF Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-def-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler is manging the name of your Add function in DllAdd. Because you're compiling it with the a C++ compiler which allows for function name overloading. The way to resolve this is as I mentioned either compile it as a C project or prevent your compiler from renaming or name mangling the function like so.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

`extern "C"` will prevent your compiler from altering it.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know extern "C" did that! In the long run changing my project from cpp to C won't be the best solution so extern "C" will work really well.. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Kayla or you can use `__pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__));` inside function body. this print real function name for you, when you compile. and then use something like `"?Add@@YAHHH@Z"` in call `GetProcAddress`

Answer (score 1):

You are running into a name decoration issue. The function is being exported with C++ name decoration (telling the language what the parameters are, and some other information), but you are importing the bare name instead.

Add `extern "C"` to your DLL's definition and all should be well. Note, however, that even with `extern "C"`, if you were to change to a 32-bit build, the name would no longer be just `Add` but `_Add` instead. And if you used `__stdcall`, the name would also change (again, only for 32-bit builds).

```
extern "C"
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Add(int x, int y)
...
```

Either that, or use a tool like dumpbin/objdump (depending on whether you are using the MS tools or gcc) to see the actual name being exported.

Comment: does explicitly stating a calling convention as `__cdecl` when compiling 64bit make a difference here? If I'm compiling both as 64 bit I should assume the compiler chooses the correct calling convention right? Since it's 64 bit I don't even know if it's actually using the cdecl convention regardless of explicitly stating it

Comment: Explicitly stating "__cdecl" only makes a difference if you've used the command line to change the default calling convention (very unlikely as doing that makes all the standard includes break).

Comment: @Kayla calling conventions like `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` do not exist in 64bit, so they will simply be ignored by the compiler.  There is only 1 [64-bit calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention), and it is dictated by the x64 ABI.